# Allow some URL without security

Tags: spring-security

Actually I would like to authorize every URL without security, so in a class who extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` I have

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .cors().configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues())
            .and() // (1)
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/v1/billingaccount/*").permitAll() 
            .antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs").permitAll()
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated() // (2)
            .and()
        .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt() // (3)
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter());
}
```

I tried to do a `DELETE` via Postman

```
http://localhost:8083/v1/billingaccount/1003
```

and I get a 401 error.

No issue to call

```
http://localhost:8083/v2/api-docs
```

Comment: Did you import `HttpMethod` from package `org.springframework.http`?

Comment: And remove your second `authorizeRequests()` it is not neccessary.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two asterisks (*).

`.antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/v1/billingaccount/**").permitAll()`